# Data for Tracy-Widom distribution

Tags: statistics

I have data for a random variable and I wish to test whether it conforms to the Tracy-Widom distribution. However, the T-W distribution is hard to compute. Is there a readly available table of its values I can just download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually not all that complicated to calculate the Tracy-Widom CDF just from its definition: see [*On The Numerical Evaluation Of Fredholm Determinants* by Folkmar Bornemann](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2543). The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy%E2%80%93Widom_distribution) gives the definition as
$$ F_2(s) = \det(I - A_s), $$
where $A_s$ is the integral operator on $[s,\infty)$ with the kernel
$$ 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ai}{Ai}
K(x,y) = \frac{\Ai(x)\Ai'(y)-\Ai'(x)\Ai(y)}{x-y}, $$
$$ A_s[f](x) = \int_s^\infty K(x,y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y. $$

Just going from this, you can take the weights $w_i$ and nodes $x_i$ of any good quadrature rule on the interval $[s,\infty)$, such as the excellent [tanh-sinh quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature), and compute the determinant of the matrix
$$ \det\big( \delta_{ij} - w_i^{1/2} K(x_i, x_j) w_j^{1/2}\big)_{i,j}. $$
This works because the kernel is smooth.

To make sure this actually works, I wrote the code below (using Julia 0.6): there is a little bit of inaccuracy at $F_2(-8)$, but it's fine otherwise. Most of the time is spent calculating Airy functions, so it should be okay for generating tables of values for future use.

```
module TracyWidom

using SpecialFunctions
using Base.Test

function K(x, y)
  try
    if x == y
      airyaiprime(x)^2 - x * airyai(x)^2
    else
      (airyai(x)*airyaiprime(y) - airyaiprime(x)*airyai(y)) / (x - y)
    end
  catch ex # underflow is not an error here
    if isa(ex, SpecialFunctions.AmosException) && ex.id == 4
      return 0.0
    else
      rethrow(ex)
    end
  end
end

function tanhSinhNodes(s, n=64)
  tf = 3.158587875883174 # fzero(t -> log1p(-tanh(pi/2*sinh(t))) - log(eps(typeof(s))), 3.1)
  t = linspace(-tf, tf, 2n+1)
  u = tanh.(pi/2*sinh.(t))
  w = pi/2*cosh.(t)./cosh.(pi/2*sinh.(t)).^2
  w * step(t) .* 2./(u-1).^2, s + (u+1) ./ (1-u)
end

function tanhSinh(f, s, n=64)
  w, x = tanhSinhNodes(s, n)
  dot(w, f.(x))
end

function F2(s, n=128)
  w, x = tanhSinhNodes(s, n)
  m = length(w)
  det([Int(i==j) - sqrt(w[i])*sqrt(w[j])*K(x[i], x[j]) for i=1:m, j=1:m])
end

function test()
  @testset "TracyWidom" begin
    @testset "tanh-sinh" begin
      @test tanhSinh(x -> 1/(1+x^2), 0., 32) ≈ π/2
      @test tanhSinh(x -> 1/(1+x^2), 1., 32) ≈ π/2 - atan(1.)
      @test tanhSinh(x -> (1+x^2)^-1.25, 2.0, 32) ≈ 0.20885622523501382
    end

    @testset "F2" begin
      @test F2(0.1) ≈ 0.9754704606594619
      @test F2(-0.1) ≈ 0.9620142937272265
      @test F2(-1.0) ≈ 0.8072142419992853
      @test F2(-2.0) ≈ 0.41322414250512257
      @test F2(-3.0) ≈ 0.08031955293933454
      @test F2(-4.0) ≈ 0.0035445535955092003
      @test F2(-5.0) ≈ 2.135996984741116e-5
      @test F2(-6.0) ≈ 1.062254674124451e-8
      @test F2(-7.0) ≈ 2.639614767246062e-13
      @test F2(-8.0) ≈ 1.9859004257636574e-19

      @test F2(1.0) ≈ 0.9975054381493893
      @test F2(2.0) ≈ 0.9998875536983092
      @test F2(3.0) ≈ 0.9999970059566077
      @test F2(4.0) ≈ 0.9999999504208784
      @test F2(5.0) ≈ 0.9999999994682207
      @test F2(6.0) ≈ 0.9999999999961827
      @test F2(7.0) ≈ 0.9999999999999811
      @test F2(8.0) ≈ 0.9999999999999999
    end
  end
  nothing
end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica has the TW distributions:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracyWidomDistribution.html